# Why does image.network() reduce the quality of my images?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am working on an application for my organisation android 60" TV, I upload the images link in my Firebase realtime database but when the TV's try to access them,they are reduced in quality .... NOTE:The images are 4K.....
but on display they are not high definition....why is this?How can i solve this?

```
if (snapshot.hasError) {
    return _defaultImage();
} else {
   String url = _switchFunction(snapshot.data);
   return Image.network(
      '$url',
       fit: BoxFit.cover,
       height: double.infinity,
       width: double.infinity,
   );
}
```

Comment: Reduced quality or is it simply distorted? I ask because you're fit is set to "fill" so it will likely distort the image. A better option is BoxFit.cover.

Answer (score 0):

Image.network() does not reduce or distort the image .It can be possible that your image's height/width  is small and you want to set with infinite height and width that's why your image is distorted.

You need to change image's height and width with fit or you may try with height/width and fit like below:

```
Image.network(
      '$url'
    ),
```

Comment: yes...infact the app crashes when i use the original image.....Is it possible that png images loose the quality when uploaded?is there an easier way to get an image url ?

Comment: I don't think that png image loose the quality after uploading.